# Merge all child values back into the parent multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and i need to merge all the child values back into its parent.

Say i have an array like this:

```
array(2) {

      [XY] =>
      array(3) {
                [A]=> 20
                [B]=> 30
                [2]=>
                array(2) {
                          [0]=> 1
                          [1]=> 2
                         }
               }
      [YZ] =>
      array(3) {
                [A]=> 60
                [B]=> 50
                [2]=>
                array(2) {
                          [0]=> 3
                          [1]=> 4
                         }
               }
}
```

and i want an output like this:

```
array(2) {

      [XY] =>
      array(4) {

                [A]=> 20
                [B]=> 30
                [2]=> 1
                [3]=> 2  
               }
      [YZ] =>
      array(4) {

                [A]=> 60
                [B]=> 50
                [2]=> 3
                [3]=> 4                             
               }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution its work recursive and give any child to meta parent (lvl 1 parent) note:end level Childs give to lvl 1 parent

```
    function giveChildToParentLevel($array)
    {

       $countOfArray = count($array);

       foreach($array as $key=>$value)
       {

           if(is_array($value))
           {

               $childitems = giveChildToParentLevel($value);

               if(count($childitems) > 0 )
               {
                   unset($array[$key]);
                   $i = 0;
                   foreach($childitems as $child)
                   {
                       if($i == 0)
                             $array[$key] = $child;
                       else
                            $array[$key.$i] = $child;

                       $i++;
                   }
               }


           }


       }

        return $array;
    }

    $array = //your array;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        $array[$key] = giveChildToParentLevel($value);
    }
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying. but this is returning me only the child array which is not correct as per my requirement.

Comment: @JasveenKaur i updated my answer see how i use it in end of the code

Answer (score 0):

This code will merge the entire child `array` into its main parent array, similarly you can do for your requirements.

```
foreach($allDataInarray as $key => $data) {
    $array_keys = array_keys($data);
    foreach($array_keys as $key_value) {
        if(is_array($data[$key_value])) {
            foreach($data[$key_value] as $sub_key => $sub_data) {
                $allDataInarray[$key][$sub_key] = $sub_data;   
            }
            unset($allDataInarray[$key][$key_value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this is for 2D array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain more about your answer. I don't understand how this can be applied to the user's question Also, read about [How to Answer a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write effective answers.